# NHibernate select from multiple tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

As the title says, I need to make a query like such. In my database I have a table `House` and a table `Room` and I now want to be able to make a **query based on the `houseId` from `House` table and `roomId` from `Room` table**, since `roomId`s are only unique for each house, not globally for entire table. How would I do that in NHibernate Fluent?

I would need something like this:

```
Room room = (session.QueryOver<Room>()
                .JoinQueryOver<House>()
                .Where(r => r.Number == roomNumber) && (h => h.Id == houseId);
```

But in a proper Fluent syntax and manner. I could not find similar examples over the internet.

Also, i tried with subquery, but I got this error that subquery can not be inferred from usage!

```
var subquery = session.QueryOver<House>()
                .Where(h => h.Name == houseName);


var query = session.QueryOver<Room>(() => room)
                .Where(r => r.Number == roomNumber)
                .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(() => roomNumber)
                .In(subquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the relation between `House` and `Room`, but let expect that *Room* contains `HouseId`.

Version with SubQuery then could be like this:

```
var houseName = "...";
var roomNumber = ...;

// prefilter houses
// first change fromt he question above here is
// that we instead of session.QueryOver
// have to use detached version: QueryOver.Of
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<House>()
    .Where(h => h.Name == houseName)
    // each subquery also MUST return something
    // here the ID - house ID,  to be later use for match
    .Select(x => x.ID)
    ;

Room room = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Room>(() => room)
    .Where(r => r.ContactPositionId == roomNumber)
    // take rooms, which house id fits
    .WithSubquery
        // the room's property HouseID
        .WhereProperty(() => room.HouseId)
        // IS IN (...)
        .In(subquery)
    ;

// later the list
var list = query
    .Take(10)
    .List<Room>();
```

The version with a join could be like this:

```
Room room = null;
House house = null;

var searchedRoom = session.QueryOver<Room>(() => room)
    .JoinQueryOver<House>(r => r.House, () => house)
    .Where(() => room.RoomNumber == roomNumber)
    .And(() => house.Name == houseName)
    .Take(1)
    .List<Room>()
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ;
```